# Silverlight local storage

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

As you may know Silverlight has support for local storage. We are looking at creating Sl application that will work in off line mode.

This application may require quite a bit of data to be cached on the client side.

Obvious solution - use local storage with some sort of XMl based structure won't work as our PoC showed due to performance issues.

We are looking at several 3rd party solutions that implement light database engines on top of SL local storage.

If you have solved this problem in the past or have any ideas - I would appreciate some pointers and ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a client side object database that is worth looking into.

http://siaqodb.com/

Comment: Thanks. We found this solution to be slower and currently planning on using: http://www.mcobject.com/perst

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution and alternatives